# Boot Camp Windows installation interrupted by an error. Disk divided into 2 different containers. I am unable to combine them

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

My disk was only 1 part. I tried to install Windows using Boot Camp. I followed the steps mentioned on the official Apple website, but I got an error message while installation.

When I checked my disk status, I have 2 disk part now:

Container 1: 86.55 GB, empty
Container 2: 156 GB, MacintoshHD

I want to make my disk only 1 part again. The screenshots show the current state of the disk.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I combine the two parts?